# Command line tool to search docx file under ms dos or cygwin

Tags: windows-xp, command-line, search, cygwin, docx

Is there a command line tool that is able to search `.docx` file under MS DOS or Cygwin ?

I have tried Grep, it's not working with `.docx` while working fine with `.txt` file.

I know I could always convert the `.docx` to `.txt` 1st then search using Grep, but I am wondering:

*Is there a command tool that I can search directly under command line?*

OP edit: Later I found out that the easiest way to achieve the grep is actually to convert those docx to txt then grep over them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many libraries allowing to read or otherwise manipulate DOCX files. Thinking of [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/), or [python-docx](https://github.com/mikemaccana/python-docx), for example. I don't know if there is already a wrapper which would allow you to grep a DOCX, but that would most certainly not be too hard to do using POI (I have no experience with python-docx. It might still be a faster solution.).

EDIT:

Also, simpler, you might unzip the DOCX (because it's really just a ZIP file), and grep through the content, as suggested [here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2298861?start=0&tstart=0).

Comment: thanks for the links but are they command line utilitys ?

Comment: General advice: try keeping a text version of your document source. Be it LaTeX, XML, raw text, or other easily parsable formats. Helps a lot for version control and searching through many files.

Comment: @Gob00st: Well, for the last suggestion, if you have a command-line unzip, you're good to go. I just checked with my cygwin installer and you can install `unzip` anytime to complete the unzip+grep toolchain.

Comment: thanks for the advice, but this is not for my project, just trying to search some text in some MS documents faster without need to open each and every one of them.

Comment: @M: I didn't know it's a zip file... But I have just unzipped one docx file and now it's more like xmls files. The thing is I want to be able to search over a lot docx files , that's why I was trying to use grep which works great when I search a lot xml/txt files...

Comment: If DOCX is some XML files, and grep works good with XML, then you can simply use method you already know to go through them all. All you have to do is unzip a DOCX before you grep its XMLs, right?

Comment: @M: Yes grep works great with xmls. But I will have to unzip a lot of docx then do a grep with those xmls. If I cannot find a better way soon I guess I will have to use this one.

Comment: If you don't unzip them yourself, you'll use something which unzips them before doing whatever it does with them. You can't edit something while it's zipped. I wonder if there would be a way to see them as zipped folders and have windows do the zip/unzip abstraction for you... There was a Windows version where zip files appeared as folders right? Then maybe renaming DOCX extensions to ZIP the time of the search would make it just like parsing through standard folders? Thinking out loud...

Answer (score 0):

I used to use antiword/catdoc for this purpose. There has obviously been some work on expanding the functionality to include docx files as well. :-)
[http://blog.kiddaland.net/2009/07/antiword-for-office-2007/](https://web.archive.org/web/20100217083556/https://blog.kiddaland.net/2009/07/antiword-for-office-2007/)